# Remove characters from HTML string only if they appear after specific pattern

Tags: python, string, email, mime

So, I tried to google my problem but I was unable to find a satisfactory answer. I have written a program that is used to parse HTML emails. It used to work fine until now, but I guess that something has been updated in the Outlook protocol. However, now, when extracting the HTML content of the email, everything works fine except for `style` tags.

Everything that comes after `style` tag is automatically escaped for some reason. For example like this: `<span style=\'color:red; background:yellow; mso-highlight:yellow\'>` and `<span style=\'background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow\'>` Notice how the style `'` marks are escaped for some reason? This is causing problems for my software, and making it crash. I really do not need these escape markers and want to get rid of them.

So now my question is, how do I remove ONLY and ONLY (if possible) the markers in these specific places? So only after `style=` and also at the end of the style property, just before `'>`. All help is really much appreciated, I am totally and utterly stuck with no idea on how to proceed. I really wouldn't want to remove all of the backwards slashes so nothing that really needs to be escaped is not escaped.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple regular expression should work:

```
import re

text = re.sub(r"style=\'(.*)\'", r"style='\1'", raw_text)
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for! Thank you so much! My regex skills are REALLY rusty